# Get ISO DateTime with only core modules in Perl?

Tags: perl

I would like to get a date-time string such as `2015-06-17 10:20:34` with only core modules. The reason of this is that `cpan install DateTime` takes ages on my machine because of the tests and the fetch of all the dependencies.

If I give my Program to my colleagues. They will also need to install the missing modules. However, if I simply do:

```
 my $date = `date "+%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`; chomp $date;
```

It takes only one line, it requires no additional modules and works on all *POSIX* machines.

> Why should I need to install `DateTime` in this case?

Yet `DateTime->now` is the solution recommended by google. I think it shouldn't, I think I am wrong and I can't figure out why.

Comment: What Perl version are you using?

Comment: `$ perl -v
This is perl 5, version 14, subversion 4 (v5.14.4) built for cygwin-thread-multi-64int`

Comment: [ISO 8601 date-time format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) looks like `2015-06-17T10:20:34`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is simple with the `POSIX` function `strftime`:

```
use POSIX qw( strftime );

print strftime "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S", localtime;
```

`POSIX` has been core since 5.0.

Answer (score 7):

Perl 5.14 contains the [core module Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/5.14.2/Time/Piece.html), which has a `datetime` method that returns a date and time in ISO 8601.

```
use Time::Piece;
my $t = localtime;
say $t->datetime;
```

This will return `2015-06-17T10:59:15`. If you don't want the `T`, remove it.

```
say localtime->datetime =~ y/T/ /r;
```

Comment: `Time::Piece` is core as of 5.9.5. (You can see this with `corelist Time::Piece`)

Comment: Why not just use `strftime` directly and give it the wanted format? Seems far better than taking a different format then regexping it.

Comment: True @LeoNerd. But well, I'll leave it since I think a lot of people keep forgetting about Time::Piece, me included. ;)

Comment: I think he meant T::P's `strftime`

Comment: Also the OP asked for the _ISO_ date and time, which has the `T`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=ISO_8601, so it kind of makes sense to use that method.

Answer (score 4):

The [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Time::Piece) module has been in core Perl since version 5.10, about eight years ago

It overrides the `localtime` core function and looks like this

```
use Time::Piece;

print localtime->datetime;
```

**output**

```
2015-06-17T12:55:36
```

If you *really* want a space instead of the standard `T` then, on Perl v5.14 or later you can write

```
print localtime->datetime =~ tr/T/ /r;
```

In earler versions, which don't have the `/r` "non-destructive" option, you would have to put the string into a variable and modify it with `tr/T/ /`

Answer (score 1):

Time::Piece gives you an object with many useful methods. As other people have pointed out, the `datetime()` gives you the date and time in ISO format.

```
use Time::Piece;

print localtime->datetime;
```

But if you want a different format (like the "not quite ISO" format in your question) you can use the `strftime()` method.

```
use Time::Piece;

print localtime->strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S');
```

A couple of other points:

- Your DateTime installation might go quicker if you used a pre-built package (for example, `yum install perl-DateTime` on a RedHat derived system).
- There are two reasons for avoiding shelling out to run system commands - firstly you lose cross-platform compatibility and secondly creating a new shell is a relatively slow and expensive operation.